# How do I get just the product name from Amazon's Product Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I feel like I must be missing something incredibly simple here, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a product's name alone from the Product Advertising API.

For instance, if I go to look [at this product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002WB2GB6), I see that the product is listed as "The First Years Ignite Stroller", and the "City Chic" color is selected.

From the API, I can see `Brand` ("The First Years") and `Color` ("City Chic"), but `Title` returns "The First Years Ignite Stroller, City Chic", with no other apparent ways to get at just the "Ignite Stroller" part, or even the title Amazon uses on their page ("The First Years Ignite Stroller").

I've considered stripping off the `Color` and `Brand` from `Title` to get there, but they're not always so predictable in their construction. Some products have different separators, others have size variants instead of colors, etc.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I don't really have a complete answer but I believe you are getting the Extended Title. The product in question is one of several different colors, all listed under the same title. I'm sure there is a reason that it is done this way but I'm unsure why.

Comment: This maybe non relevant anymore, but I tried to get the response for this item : B002WB2GB6 and I succeeded to get the correct result. The title which I'm getting is: "The First Years Ignite Stroller" which is the same as in Amazon title. Are you sure that you used the correct ASIN?

Answer (score 0):

As of Dec-19, 2018, this is not supported in the API. You may get lucky that the title is also the product name, but there simply isn't any field that contains the 'short name' for the product.

I imagine Amazon want you to use their titles and not make up your own.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_ItemAttributes.html